# what is error number 1055 and to resolve it?

Tags: mysql

> Error Number: 1055
>
> Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'qbank_stage_db.qc.ID' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with `sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

```
SELECT * FROM (admin_dash_view_mcq)
```

Filename:

> C:\wamp64\www\QBank_Stage\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330

Comment: That certainly is not the sql statement that lead to the posted error message...

Comment: Look for a query that contains `qbank_stage_db.qc.ID'`

Comment: Or show us that View Code